# Cannot find value from span using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to obtain the value of the comment from the comment box, which is only displayed if a user has left a comment.

`<div data-v-410f78e0="" class="comment"><span data-v-410f78e0="" class="title">Message: </span> <div data-v-410f78e0="" class="comment-content comment-content-inline"><div data-v-410f78e0="" class="comment-desc comment-desc-inline"><span data-v-410f78e0="">+603-779 852</span></div> <!----></div></div>`

I'm trying to get `+603-779 852` from there. I tried this

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 #Parse the HTML using Beautiful Soup
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

 #Find the element containing the string you want to extract
 element = soup.find("div", class_="comment-desc comment-desc-inline")

 #Extract the string from the element and remove any leading or trailing white space
 string = element.text.strip()

 #Remove the characters "+", "-", and space from the string
 modified_string = string.replace("+", "").replace("-", "").replace(" ", "")

 #Slice the first character (index 0) from the modified string and remove it if it contains the character "6"
 first_char = modified_string[0:1].replace("6", "")

 #Verify that the resulting string starts with the character "0"
 if first_char.startswith("0"):
   final_string = first_char + modified_string[1:]
 else:
   final_string = modified_string

 #Print the final string
 print(final_string)
```

Comment: we need the url to be able to reproduce this

Comment: since selenium is not involved anywhere in the code, the tag has been deactivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guarantee you this isn't the best way to do this. But only half my brain is working today, so this is all I've got.

As they say *"If it's stupid, but works, it ain't stupid".*

To fix your code, you can simply change:

`string = element.text.strip()`

To:

`string = element.contents[0].contents[0]`

Complete Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """<div data-v-410f78e0="" class="comment"><span data-v-410f78e0="" class="title">Message: </span> <div data-v-410f78e0="" class="comment-content comment-content-inline"><div data-v-410f78e0="" class="comment-desc comment-desc-inline"><span data-v-410f78e0="">+603-779 852</span></div> <!----></div></div>"""
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")

#Find the element containing the string you want to extract
element = soup.find("div", class_="comment-desc comment-desc-inline")

#Extract the string from the element and remove any leading or trailing white space
string = element.contents[0].contents[0]

#Remove the characters "+", "-", and space from the string
modified_string = string.replace("+", "").replace("-", "").replace(" ", "")

#Slice the first character (index 0) from the modified string and remove it if it contains the character "6"
first_char = modified_string[0:1].replace("6", "")

#Verify that the resulting string starts with the character "0"
if first_char.startswith("0"):
    final_string = first_char + modified_string[1:]
else:
    final_string = modified_string

#Print the final string
print(final_string)
```

Will output:

`603779852`

Comment: Omg, thank you. You are my first hero in 2023